# how to click on the sub element in WebDriver/Java

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

The below is the HTML code...here i just wanna click on the cssselector(span.icon_edit ClsUpdate) in span tag..

```
<div class="final_textarea">
    <div class="tab_lable_right">
    <textarea rows="2" cols="50" id="txttab_2" readonly="readonly" class="input col_10 input_medium box_radius clscopypaste" oncopy="return false" oncut="return false" data-columnid="20" data-columnname="Member Services Link
    " data-preval="ABC insurance">ABC insurance</textarea>
    </div>
    <span data-columnid="20" data-columnname="Member Services Link" data-preval="ABC insurance" class="icon_edit ClsUpdate"></span>
    </div>
```

Scenario:

1. when we mouse hover on the text area
2. the span tag (span.icon_edit ClsUpdate) will enable
3. i just want to click that(span.icon_edit ClsUpdate) element.

My Web-Driver code is;

```
WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txttab_2']"));
mainMenu.click();
Thread.sleep(3000);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"icon_edit ClsUpdate\"]")));
element.click();
```

Error;

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //span[@class="icon_edit ClsUpdate"]
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'Axxxxx-J008', ip: '10.10.6.22', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
```

Comment: What error are you getting? NoSuchElement exception?

Answer (score 3):

You can try out your the below xpath on [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) site:

```
//span[@class="icon_edit ClsUpdate"]
```

So, your code would be:

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"icon_edit ClsUpdate\"]"));
//wait for the element to be clickable
link.click();
```

Comment: So u mean the code should like this....???  Actions actions = new Actions(driver); WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txttab_2']"));
actions.moveToElement(mainMenu).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);

WebElement subMenu = driver.findElement((By.xpath("//span[@class=\"icon_edit ClsUpdate\"]")));
actions.moveToElement(subMenu);
actions.click().build().perform();

Comment: I have no clue what you are doing with the `Actions`, but the `span` part that I have answered should work. Do a `link.isenabled()` just to be sure. Edit your question and add the error.

Comment: +for the reference to the free online xpath tester

Answer (score 0):

The following code should hover over textArea element using Action class then wait for the span tag to be located and perform click.

```
By textArea = By.cssSelector("textarea[id^='txttab']");
By spanTag = By.cssSelector("span[class='icon_edit ClsUpdate']");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(textArea);
action.moveToElement(element).perform();
WebElement span = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(spanTag));
span.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//I'm assuming your selector's are correct

WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='txttab_2']"));

mainMenu.click();

//this bit below searches inside the text area which is what i think you need and not the whole page.

final WebElement link = mainMenu.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class=\"icon_edit ClsUpdate\"]"));

link.click();
```